# Is gzip an actual ZIP file?

Tags: performance, gzip

Does a gzip contains an archive of the referenced assets, such as external JS, CSS, and images or does it only compress the one file?

If the browser has never seen the site the before and has nothing cached then it seems like a good idea to send over an actual ZIP file that the browser unpacks. Is this how it’s done?

Update: Damn you Gzip! Why can't you unzip an actual ZIP?!

Comment: re "Damn you Gzip! Why can't you unzip an actual ZIP?!" - `ZIP`'s legal status was somewhat unclear at the time when compression was in the works for browsers; `gzip` is a free implementation of a similar algorithm, but not the same (thus, ungzipping a zipped file gives unusable results; you could as well ask "why can't ZIP unpack a RAR archive?").

Answer (score 3):

Only compress one file. You need to combine compression (e.g. `gz`, `bz2` or `xz`) with an archive format (e.g. `tar` or `cpio`) to match ZIP's functionality (hence `.tar.gz` files).

Browsers pipeline multiple requests, they do not request a ZIP file. Browsers do rely on compression.

If you want to learn about this topic, look at the issues being solved by [`SPDY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) for a better understanding of the shortcomings of `HTTP`.

Comment: I see, but the browser is not going to decompress the gzipped archive correct? That's awesome Google is working on it, but it seems like gzip should upgrade to unpack an archive such as tar or something. Thanks for the good info.

Comment: @Dathan: gzip should upgrade, and then all browsers should upgrade to support it, and all webservers should upgrade to support it, not to mention proxies. If upgrading were so trivial, we wouldn't have the IE6 problem any more in 2011. (not to mention that a ZIP archive doesn't really bring any *significant* benefit compared to current state of HTTP/1.1, as opposed to SPDY)

Answer (score 2):

In case you mean web-server to web-browser communication. A webserver compresses the Response and the Browser decompresses it. But each Response will be compressed.

So in web-server to web-browser communication there will be no such thing like a multi-asset-compression.

In a more general case: GZIP compresses only "single files". You need to encapsulate them first in an archive format if you want to compress multiple files via gzip.

Comment: Got it, thanks. It still doesn't cut down on requests to linked resources. That's too bad.

Comment: @Dathan: With HTTP keepalives and pipelining, does it actually matter? The requests needn't be separate TCP connections, if that's the issue - the server will send a huge chunk of data to the client anyway, just half a level down from individual resources.

Comment: @Piskvor I see, this answers my question, gzip with keepalives is the solution I was looking for. You're very knowledgeable. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

First, gzip is a compression algorithm, so it only compresses the data given (which doesn't have to be a file, any string is compressible with gzip), it doesn't archive multiple resources together (as opposed to ZIP, which does both archiving and compression, and operates on files).

Second, I have yet to see a browser which would support ZIP compression (although it's an interesting idea). The closest I've seen is the [MHTML archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mhtml), which contains all the assets of one page; that could, in turn, be compressed with any algorithm; again, it is not universally supported.

Third, the usual way is to gzip-compress each response separately (be it HTML, JS, CSS, or whatnot - note that common image formats are already compressed, so you get no measurable benefit from compressing them again).

Comment: Yeah, MHTML has been around a long time, it's the format IE and WORD uses to save webpages offline. You could be right, I'm not sure it's the same idea as a ZIP archive. Thanks for the good info.

Comment: @Dathan: It's not the same idea at all; but as I mention in the answer, MHTML is the closest to a multi-file compressible archive (e.g. ZIP) that I've seen actually implemented in a mainstream browser. Closest, not same.

Answer (score 1):

Gzip is not a container format like zip, it is just for compressing single files. Gzip combined with tar is used to create compressed directories like the zip format.

Comment: Awesome thanks, seems like a misnomer to have zip in the name since that usually is known as an archive.

Comment: @Dathan: Uh, no. ZIP is, first and foremost, a *compression* algorithm, the archive function is something of an afterthought.